# Prove that the limit of $a_n = \frac{2n^3+n^2}{(n+2)^3}$ is $2$.

Tags: limits

if $a_n = \dfrac{2n^3+n^2}{(n+2)^3}$, prove that the limit of $a_n$ (as $n$ tends to infinite) is $2$ using the definition of a limit.

My attempt was $\left |\dfrac{(2(n^3))+(n^2)}{(n+2)^3} - 2\right |=\left |\dfrac{(2(n^3))+(n^2)-2((n+2)^3)}{(n+2)^3}\right |$ and tried to simplify it as much as I could (though I couldn't get very far) then set it to less than Epsilon.

I'm not sure if that was the right approach though. Would anyone be able to help me out on this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: Must you use the definition directly? Having some limit theorems makes short work of problems like this.

Comment: yes, its strictly using the definition of a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{2n^3+n^2-2(n+2)^3}{(n+2)^3}\right|=\frac{11n^2+24n+16}{(n+2)^3}\le\frac{11n^2+n^2+n^2}{(n+3)^3}\le13\frac{n^2}{n^3}=\frac{13}n$$

Now, show the rightmost expression is less than $\;\epsilon\;$ for $\;n\;$ big enough and also show the first *inequality* is true for all $\;n\;$ greater than...?

Comment: oh... I see now! That makes perfect sense. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n^3+n^2}{(n+2)^3}$$ $$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^3(2+\frac1n)}{n^3(1+\frac{2}{n})^3}$$
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2+\frac1n)}{(1+\frac{2}{n})^3}$$

Now, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $\frac1n\rightarrow0$
$$L=\frac{2+0}{1+0}$$
$$L=2$$

Comment: What is "$\frac1\infty$"? What is $\infty^3$? Those expressions don't make sense.

Comment: It's $1$ upon a very large number, which is practically $0$

Comment: Well, let me reframe it.

Comment: "...using the definition of limit" .

Comment: I know what you meant, but you should write what you mean ;)

Comment: Yep. I just substituted the limit, without being concerned that it cannot be done so directly. :p

Comment: $(n+2)^3\neq n^3\left(1+\dfrac2{n^3}\right)$

Comment: @columbus8myhw Sorry, corrected it. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

we will make a change of variable $u = n + 2, n = u - 2.$ then 
$\begin{align}\frac{2n^3 + n^2}{(n+2)^3} &= \frac{2(u-2)^3 + (u-2)^2}{u^3}\\
& = \dfrac{2(u^3 - 6u^2+12u -8) +(u^2-4u+4)}{u^3}\\
&= 2 -\dfrac{11}{u}+\dfrac{20}{u^2}-\dfrac{12}{u^3}\end{align}$

pick an $\epsilon < 0.1.$ choose $N$ big enough so that for $u \ge N$ we have $$\dfrac{1}{u^3} \le \dfrac{1}{u^2}\le \dfrac{1}{u} \le\dfrac{\epsilon}{43} < 0.1$$

now $$|\frac{2(u-2)^3 + (u-2)^2}{u^3} -2|=  |-\dfrac{11}{u}+\dfrac{20}{u^2}-\dfrac{12}{u^3}| \le \frac{43}{u} \le \epsilon$$

therefore $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n^3 + n^2}{(n+2)^3} = \lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{2(u-2)^3 + (u-2)^2}{u^3} = 2. $$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left|\frac{2n^3 +n^2}{(n+2)^3} - 2\right| \le \left|\left( \frac{n}{n+2} \right)^3 \left(2+\frac1{n}-2 \right)\right| + 2\left|\left( \frac{n}{n+2} \right)^3 -1 \right| \\
= \frac1{n+2}\left( \left| \left(\frac{n}{n+2} \right)^2 \right|+4\left|\left(\frac{n}{n+2} \right)^2 +\left(\frac{n}{n+2} \right) + 1 \right|\right)
\lt \frac{13}{n+2} \rightarrow 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{10}=\frac{2100}{12^3}=\frac{2.1}{1.2^3}$$
$$a_{100}=\frac{2010000}{102^3}=\frac{2.01}{1.02^3}$$
$$a_{1000}=\frac{2001000000}{1002^3}=\frac{2.01}{1.002^3}$$
$$a_{10000}=\frac{2000100000000}{10002^3}=\frac{2.0001}{1.0002^3}$$
$$\cdots$$
$$a_\infty=\frac21$$
It is enough to say that the fractional parts vanish.

Comment: I admit that this does not implement the definition of the limit explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

$$lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2(n^3))+(n^2)}{(n+2)^3}$$

When we look at limits of quotients of polynomials as $n\to\infty$, we want to look at the largest degree of the polynomial. (it is the only one that is relevant to the limit as $n\to\infty$)

Thus $lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2(n^3))+(n^2)}{(n+2)^3}= lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2(n^3)}{n^3}$

Which equals 2.

Comment: "...using the definition of limit"